TypeError getting null for nodeName in in-built (?) function
I'm trying to implement a "bold" button on my React/JS code. It works fine when I "bold" selected text, but "unbolding" previously bolded text leads to this error:
Error message
nr-ext-text-processor.js is not a function I wrote, so I'm assuming it's a dependency/in-built. But just in case, for context, these are the functions invoked by my button:
function onWrap(tag: WrapperOptions) {
    let currSelection = returnSelection();
    if (currSelection) {
      const newSelection = wrapSelection(node, currSelection, tag, reference);
      if (newSelection) {
        let newRange = new Range();
        newRange.setStartBefore(newSelection);
        newRange.setEndAfter(newSelection);
        let selection = window.getSelection();
        selection?.removeAllRanges();
        selection?.addRange(newRange);
      }

      checkRange();
      updateTree();
    }
  }
  
  function onUnwrap(tag: WrapperOptions) { // causing the issues
    let currSelection = returnSelection();
    if (currSelection && reference.current) {
      console.log('currselection.getrangeat: ', currSelection.getRangeAt(0).toString());
      const newSelection = removeTagFromRange( // my function; removes tag from selected range
        tag,
        currSelection.getRangeAt(0),
        reference.current
      );

      checkRange(); // my function
      updateTree(); // my function; updates HAST tree 
    }
  }

I've had friends try to run my code on their devices, both on the browser I'm using (Chrome) and other browsers (Firefox), but it seems like I'm the only one getting this error.
Using console.log, I know that all of these individual functions invoked within onUnwrap run and terminate succesfully-- but the error's still there.
Also, if it's helpful, I've tried deleting and redownloading my .next folder. Still nothing.
I can specify my code if you think it'd be helpful. Thanks in advance.

is the error occurring in removeTagFromRange function? which line of your code can you see in the error stack?

@JaromandaX I linked a photo of my error message. But all of the functions run and terminate properly. The error occurs at nr-ext-text-processor.js, which is not a function I wrote.
